# React set dynamic style in a component

Tags: reactjs

This has been asked several times but in my use case it's not working.  I'm sure I'm missing something.

In a functional component I do:

```
  const headerImg = {
    backgroundImage: `http://localhost:1337${data.service.main_image.url}`
  };
```

Then in a div I do the following:

```
<div className="bread-cumbs-area" style={headerImg}>
```

I'm attempting to use headerImg.backgroundImage as the background image but it's not displaying in my div.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want something like `backgroundImage: \`url('http://localhost:1337${data.service.main_image.url}')\``

Comment: Exactly! Thank you! @Nick

Comment: Okay, I will submit an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're setting the background image in CSS, you need to use the `url()` CSS function:

```js
const headerImg = {
  backgroundImage: `url('http://localhost:1337${data.service.main_image.url}')`
};
```